# ASP.NET C#, Add to gridview with textbox programmatically but in second click replace all the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am seeking assistance in implementing a functionality where I can input data into a GridView with TextBoxes through TextBoxes and DropDownLists. Subsequently, I aim to apply a multiplication operation each time a specific button is clicked. Once this multiplication is done, my intention is to edit if need the gridview and execute another button click event to save the modified data.

This is the `.aspx` markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientInstanceName="GridView1" runat="server"
     AllowSorting="True" AllowGroup="True" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
     DataMember="DefaultView" ForeColor="#333333">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nid" SortExpression="nid" Visible="True" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tipo" SortExpression="Tipo" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Diâmetro" SortExpression="Diâmetro" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Espessura" SortExpression="Espessura" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qualidade" SortExpression="Qualidade" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="Box6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Costura" SortExpression="Costura" >
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="Box7" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Medida" SortExpression="Medida" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heat_Number" SortExpression="Heat_Number" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Obra" SortExpression="Obra" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receção" SortExpression="Receção" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Observações" SortExpression="Observações">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The code I tried in C# code-behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CheckBox = System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;
using TextBox = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;

namespace Lista_Tubos_e_Vigas
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string comentario = txtComentario1.Value;
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string comentario = txtComentario2.Value;
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string comentario = txtComentario3.Value;
        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string comentario = txtComentario4.Value;
        }

        protected void Gravar1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            String sql2, Output = " ";

            connectionString = @"Server=AGUA;Database=PIPEMASTERS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            cnn.Open();

            sql2 = "insert into dytable (dytablestamp, campo, entityname, ousrinis, ousrdata, ousrhora, usrinis, usrdata, usrhora) select left(newid(),25), '" + txtComentario1.InnerText + "', 'u_ltv1', '', getdate(), '', '', getdate(),''";

            command = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0);
            }

            command.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();

            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string display = Output;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Registado com sucesso');window.location.href='/WebForm1.aspx?';", true);

            // Response.Redirect("http://Lista_Tubos_e_Vigas.pipemasters.pt/WebForm1.aspx");

            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('checking');window.location.href='PHC.aspx';", true);
            // Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
        }

        protected void Gravar2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            String sql2, Output = " ";

            connectionString = @"Server=AGUA;Database=PIPEMASTERS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            cnn.Open();

            sql2 = "insert into dytable (dytablestamp, campo, entityname, ousrinis, ousrdata, ousrhora, usrinis, usrdata, usrhora) select  left(newid(),25), '" + txtComentario2.InnerText + "', 'u_ltv2', '', getdate(), '', '', getdate(),''";

            command = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0);
            }

            command.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();

            // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string display = Output;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Registado com sucesso');window.location.href='/WebForm1.aspx?';", true);

            // Response.Redirect("http://Lista_Tubos_e_Vigas.pipemasters.pt/WebForm1.aspx");

            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('checking');window.location.href='PHC.aspx';", true);
            // Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
        }

        protected void Gravar3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            String sql2, Output = " ";

            connectionString = @"Server=AGUA;Database=PIPEMASTERS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();

            sql2 = "insert into dytable (dytablestamp, campo, entityname, ousrinis, ousrdata, ousrhora, usrinis, usrdata, usrhora) select  left(newid(),25), '" + txtComentario3.InnerText + "', 'u_ltv3', '', getdate(), '', '', getdate(),''";

            command = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0);
            }

            command.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();

            // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string display = Output;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Registado com sucesso');window.location.href='/WebForm1.aspx?';", true);

            // Response.Redirect("http://Lista_Tubos_e_Vigas.pipemasters.pt/WebForm1.aspx");
            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('checking');window.location.href='PHC.aspx';", true);
            // Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
            // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
        }

    protected void Gravar4_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;


        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        String sql2, Output = " ";


        connetionString = @"Server=AGUA;Database=PIPEMASTERS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        cnn.Open();

        sql2 = "insert into  dytable (dytablestamp, campo, entityname, ousrinis, ousrdata, ousrhora, usrinis, usrdata, usrhora) select  left(newid(),25), '" + txtComentario4.InnerText + "', 'u_ltv4', '', getdate(), '', '', getdate(),''";

        command = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn);

        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0);
        }


        command.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();

        //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string display = Output;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Registado com sucesso');window.location.href='/WebForm1.aspx?';", true);


        //Response.Redirect("http://Lista_Tubos_e_Vigas.pipemasters.pt/WebForm1.aspx");

        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('checking');window.location.href='PHC.aspx';", true);
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);


    }


    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int va = (int)ViewState["valorArmazenado"];
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(va));

        string multiplicador = TextBox4.Text;

        //string x_tipo = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        //string x_pol = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        //string x_esp = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
        //string x_qual = DropDownList5.SelectedValue;



        //string x_medida = TextBox1.Text;
        //string x_heatn = TextBox2.Text;

        string x_fref = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
        //string x_rec = TextBox3.Text;
        int x_nid = 0;



        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string nomeDaColuna = "nid"; // Substitua pelo nome correto da coluna
            int columnIndex = -1; // Índice inicial inválido

            // Encontre o índice da coluna pelo nome do cabeçalho
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText == nomeDaColuna)
                {
                    columnIndex = i;
                    // Display a message box
                    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(i));
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (columnIndex != -1)
            {
                int ultimoValor = int.MinValue; // Valor inicial menor possível

                // Percorra as linhas da GridView
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    // Encontre o TextBox dentro da célula da coluna
                    TextBox textBox = row.Cells[columnIndex].FindControl("Box2") as TextBox;
                    if (textBox != null && int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out int valorCelula))
                    {

                        if (valorCelula > ultimoValor)
                        {
                            ultimoValor = valorCelula;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (ultimoValor != int.MinValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Último valor numérico: {ultimoValor}");
                    // Faça o que você precisa com o valor aqui
                    x_nid = ultimoValor + 1;
                    // Display a message box
                    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(x_nid));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Não foram encontrados valores numéricos na coluna.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A coluna não foi encontrada na GridView.");
            }
        }



        else
        {
            string connetionString = @"Server=AGUA;Database=PIPEMASTERS ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";
            string query = "select isnull(max(nid),0)  + 1 as nid from u_aprov where fref = '" + x_fref + "' ";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            x_nid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["nid"]);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Último valor: {x_nid}");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Não foram encontrados valores.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        int numeroInt = int.Parse(multiplicador);
        DataTable dt;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
        {

            dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Tipo", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Diâmetro", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Espessura", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Qualidade", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Costura", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Medida", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Heat Number", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Obra", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Receção", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Observações", typeof(string));




            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        

        }

        else
        {
            dt = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
        }


        int z_nid = dt.Rows.Count;
        int novoNid = z_nid + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < numeroInt; i++)

        {

            // Adicionar alguns dados de exemplo
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            //dt.Rows.Add("y" + x_nid, x_nid, x_tipo, x_pol, x_esp, x_qual, x_Cost, x_medida, x_heatn, x_fref, x_rec, "");
            dr["ID"] = string.Empty;
            dr["nid"] = 0;
            dr["Tipo"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Diâmetro"] = 0;
            dr["Espessura"] = 0;
            dr["Qualidade"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Costura"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Medida"] = 0;
            dr["Heat Number"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Obra"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Receção"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Observações"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;


        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            if (i >= z_nid)
            {


                string x_tipo = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                string x_pol = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
                string x_esp = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
                string x_qual = DropDownList5.SelectedValue;
                string x_medida = TextBox1.Text;
                string x_heatn = TextBox2.Text;
                //string x_fref = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
                string x_rec = TextBox3.Text;



                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box1")).Text = "y" + novoNid;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box2")).Text = Convert.ToString(novoNid);
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box3")).Text = x_tipo;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box4")).Text = x_pol;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box5")).Text = x_esp;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box6")).Text = x_qual;
                CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)CheckBox1.FindControl("CheckBox1");
                if (chkUpdate.Checked)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Box7")).Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Box7")).Checked = false;
                }
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box8")).Text = x_medida;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box9")).Text = x_heatn;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box10")).Text = x_fref;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box11")).Text = x_rec;
                ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Box12")).Text = "";



                novoNid++;

            }
        }




        //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        ////GridView1.DataBind();
        //ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        //ViewState["valorArmazenado"] = va + novoNid; // Armazena o valor na primeira vez que o botão é clicado




        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

}
```

With this code, on the second click, the initially added rows are being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have way too many buttons.

And why have some areas to enter values, and then try to send to the GridView? Why not just let the user enter values right into the GridView?

And why have some buttons to do some calculations here? Why not have the numbers update when the user changes a buttons value in the GridView?

You want to think of this solution in terms of the end user.

From their point of view, they don't think of code or database operations.

All they see is a page, with some data, and they will look for a simple (single) save button when done. I suggest you adopt the same.

Think of uses having used Excel, or word.
Or even some accounting program.

They all tend to assume (and want) and look for a simple save button.

Say, like this:

[image]

You perhaps will have to expand on why the need for so many "calculation" buttons.

Same goes for the drop downs. Why not place them in the grid display?

The only UI design why you would need/want separate boxes in a separate editor area from the grid or table view is if the data form has "more" columns then what displays comfortable in that GridView.

Say like this example:

[image]

so, in above, since the row "really" does have more columns than what the grid displays, then sure, having a button to launch/edit a "form" to edit the data (or add the data) makes a lot of sense.

However, let's get back to the question:

How can a grid row button click, or even a combo box change/selection gain use of the one data row, and the controls (and values) for that one row?

The simplest is to use "naming container", and it works for Repeater, GridView, ListView etc.

And for this sample code, I going to use a ListView in place of a GridView. While the code is near identical in use, I find the ListView is a better choice then a GridView.

The reason is that for each standard asp.net control you drop into the layout area does NOT require those extra lines of "Template field" and then also an "ItemTemplate". This starts to make the markup REALLY messy in a real hurry.

I mean, if have just 8 controls, then you wind up with 16 lines of markup of

```
<TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     your ONE control here!
  </ItemTemplate>
<TemplateField>
```

So, we wind up with 5 lines of markup for JUST ONE control!!!!

Ok, so let's setup this example:

We will enter some people into a table display, and in that table, we will select a hotel from a drop down, and that dropdown will thus set the hotel nightly rate. In that same row, we will be able to enter the nights. Hence, we thus will require a calculation (number of nights X night rate).
So, we have to get the row, and then modify of some of the controls on that ONE row.

And since we dumping all of our calculation buttons, we might as well even dump the text box(s) and dropdown's outside of the GridView.

And with above, we can then have ONE simple save button at the bottom to save the edits.

So, first, let's deal with how to get the row information on a simple grid button row click.

So, here is our markup:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover borderhide"                
        width="40%" 
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' >
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' >
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Per night" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtRate" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("NightRate","{0:c2}") %>' >
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtPrice" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:c2}") %>' >
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Button" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Test"
                        OnClick="cmdTest_Click" CssClass="btn"                                
                        />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM vPeopleBook ORDER BY LastName");
        GridView1.DataBind();   
    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Ok, so now the button click event code.

```
    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
        int RowIndex = gRow.RowIndex;
        TextBox txtHotel = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("txtHotel");

        Debug.Print($"data base PK id = {PK} \n" +
                    $"Row index click = {RowIndex} \n" +
                    $"Hotel name = {txtHotel.Text}");

    }
```

Output:

```
data base PK id = 27 
Row index click = 4 
Hotel name = Swiss Village
```

So, as above shows, we can get the row index click. The hidden database PK id (nice, since we don't expose PK to client-side browser). And then we pull out the text box from that one row.

Note that the above works for any control. So, in place of a button, we could for example drop in a combo box to select a hotel. (And then set the row's night rate). (We would use auto post back, and use the combo box selected index change event.